# Program parameters to main in c - ./dev --print

Tags: c, parameters, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a program check whether the user is passing a program parameter when running the program. fx:

```
./dev --print
```

I came up with the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char print[] = "--print";
  if(strcmp(argv[1], print) == 0) {
    solve_a_bunch_of_functions_and_print_without_user_input();
  }
  else {
    ask_for_user_input();
    then_solve_bunch_of_functions();
  }
}
```

**Is this the correct / smartest way to do so?**

Currently I am experiencing issues with seg-faults after this implementation for everytime i get into the else statement. Not sure my implementation here has anything to do with it.

Comment: If no arguments are passed, then `argv[1]` will be `NULL`, and passing `NULL` to `strcmp` doesn’t work. You might want to loop over each argument, compare it to known values, set some booleans based off of that. That’s the usual getopt pattern (which might also be something you want to use).

Comment: You are right. Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's one way although I think most C programmers wouldn't bother with the separate variable, and just do:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "--print") == 0)
```

Of course, you should first validate that there *is* an argument in `argv[1]`, by checking `argc`, too. Otherwise you're passing `NULL` to `strcmp()`, which is a bad idea.

```
if(argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "--print") == 0)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely cleaner.